# how can i get app store link before approve by apple

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application mail send to someone and in this mail my client want to send a link of my application in message body while my application still not approved by apple then how can i get this link?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an app in iTunesConnect , you can see a link "View in App Store"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click your app.

[image]

You see "View in App Store"? Copy it. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the app on iTunesConnect and give them the metadata about it (name, etc). Then you can go to the app's page and copy the "view in App Store" link. This should be active even before the App is marked as "ready for sale"

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the app id to the following link:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/
```

for example

[**https://itunes.apple.com/app/id871299723**](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id871299723)